# Process separately different ajax responses to $post success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a `$.post` function, sending data to a file that procesess many information, and that file can give back different messages on the same call. I am trying to process those messages, identifying them and doing whatever action each one is ment to do:

```
$.post('../actions/checkMsg.php',{ca_id:idCampaign}).success(
            function(checkData){
                aviso=0;
                if (checkData.indexOf("counter") >= 0){
                    var value = checkData.substr(checkData.indexOf("?") + 1);
                    $('.totalRegistros span').html(value);
                    progress.update(n=1);
                }
                else if (checkData.indexOf("aviso") >= 0){
                    var value = checkData.substr(checkData.indexOf("?") + 1);
                    aviso++;
                    $('.totalAvisos span').html(aviso);
                }
            });
}
```

The `checkMsg.php` file can echo messages like **"counter?12"**, so that `value` 12 goes as `$('.totalRegistros span').html(value);`

But on the point that it can also echo things like **"aviso?There are empty fields"**, then the whole response goes toghether, at the same time (I'd like to catch each message on the moment of its creation) as a single string: **"counter?7aviso?There are empty fields"**

How should I send messages from `checkMsg.php` to make jQuery know them on real time? And separately: individual messages to be processed on real time.

Here's `checkMsg.php` related code with echoes sending this info:

```
$countMsg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ws_campmsg WHERE cm_fk_ca_id='$ca_id'");
    $totalRegistros=mysqli_num_rows($countMsg);
    echo "counter?".$totalRegistros;

    //INSPECCIÓN DE VARIABLES
    $vars1=0; $vars2=0; $vars3=0; $hasVar1=0; $hasVar2=0; $hasVar3=0;
    while($registroMsgs = mysqli_fetch_array($countMsg)){
        if ($registroMsgs['cm_var1']!==""){            
            $vars1++;
            $hasVar1=1;
        }        
        if ($registroMsgs['cm_var2']!==""){
            $vars2++;
            $hasVar2=1;
        }
        if ($registroMsgs['cm_var3']!==""){                
            $vars3++;
            $hasVar3=1;
        }
    }   

    if ($hasVar1==1 && $hasVar2==1 && $vars1 != $vars2){

        if(($hasVar3==1) && ($vars3 != $vars2 || $vars3 != $vars1)){            
            echo "aviso?Algunos de los ".$totalRegistros." no tienen variables asignadas: Hay ".$vars1." variables de tipo 1 asignadas, ".$vars2." variables de tipo 2 asignadas y ".$vars3." variables de tipo 3 asignadas.";
        }        
        else{            
            echo "aviso?Algunos de los ".$totalRegistros." no tienen variables asignadas: Hay ".$vars1." variables de tipo 1 asignadas, y ".$vars2." variables de tipo 2 asignadas.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: make a php array and send back as json. Much easier to use the properties in response object than it is to parse your string approach and will be much easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing a lot of work to parse the data on the JSON end when PHP can simplify this for you. Here's a simple change to your PHP

```
$data = array();
$data['success'] = false;
$data['aviso'] = array('Your message here', 'Another Message', 'One more message');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And then this in your jQuery function. Note that `checkData` will be recognized as JSON and then parsed automatically

```
function(checkData) {
    if(checkData.success) {
        //Successful AJAX call
    } else {
        $(checkData.aviso).each(function(index, msg) { alert(msg); });
    }
}
```

Putting your responses into JSON is the cleanest and easiest way to get the data you want. Don't reinvent the wheel and it will be easier to work on in the future

Comment: Thank you, I am about to try this

Comment: But is data sent at the same time on the unique rray, isnt it? Is there no possibility of making several independent sendings, in order to update info on real time?

Comment: Ok I'm trying but I'm facing a problem: I have set to test this: if(checkData.counter) {alert("counter");}  even when Firebug says that the php response is {"counter":7} no alert pops.

Comment: Be sure you're referencing the return object and don't treat it as a string `if(checkData.counter) {alert(checkData.counter);}`

Comment: Bad example I used, sorry. I wanted the word "counter" to be alerted, I did not treat it as a string. But neither alerting a string or counter value makes effect. Firebug says {"counter":7} is being given back but function does not work. Here the function is: http://i.imgur.com/ah0eAYn.png

Comment: Try removing `success()` and making your anonymous function the third parameter of `$.post()`

Comment: It worked with var json = $.parseJSON(checkData); and then alerting json.counter and so :)

Comment: But when I try to make several echoes, one for each individual message, an error emerges. I am afraid this can just send a single final array as response

Comment: Make it a multidimensional array then

Comment: Added a multidimensional example

Comment: Or route your requests to unique server endpoints so you can know without checking that the response matches your request, or pass something more meaningful than a counter as an identifier in the request parameters and have server return that identifier with the response.